# Mushy Aglaonema stem with browning leaf tips. Answer asap please

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

Recently I've been watering my Aglaonema Silver Bay a little too much (due to the scorching heat of summer in India). I've noticed that the stem has gotten pretty mushy and dark brownish. The plant cannot stand erect when I move it. It dangles. The tips of all the leaves have started browning too. The pups around the plant seem unaffected by the excessive watering. How can I save my plant? Please answer asap.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stem is dying due to over watering which has led to root rot.

You can cut the stem above the dying area and root the top of the cutting in water.  Then cut the stem below the dying area and provide more sun and less water.  It may bud out and regrow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way that the plant could dry out the mushy area and replenish overtime? What about the pups surrounding it? Is it better to replant them in dry and fresh soil rather than letting them sit in the wet soil? Will doing so disturb the root ball?

Comment: @FariyalAjrad The plant is already stressed so splitting the root ball will only add more stress.  I would not recommend this.  The mushy area will not "heal" as plants do not recover from injuries in the same way that people do.  Move the plant to more light and that will do wonders